# C# Inherit a Class within a Form

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have been pulling my hair out for awhile

I have created a form filled with pictureboxs. Each picturebox will contain a _click, _mousedown and _mouseup event. I wish to move these events created for the form into a class1.cs and then have form1.cs inherit these events.

I do not wish to make the picturebox1 public. 
so something such as 
Class1 classOne = new Class1(); 
pictureBox1.Click += new EventHandler(cs.pictureBox1_Click); will not work.

I am unsure how to make form1.cs inherit class1.cs. sounds so easy in my head but im just at a mental blank

I have tired class Form1 : Form, Class1

in Form1.Designer.cs this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click); 
this.pictureBox1_Click can not be accessed

if you could point me in the right direct it will be a great help! Cheers

```
Form1.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

Class1.cs 
class Class1
{

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pb1 click");
    }
 }
```

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes, so your Form1 can inherit from Form or from Class1 but not both. You can make Class1 inherit Form, and then Form1 inherit Class1.

Answer (score 3):

`Class1` should inherit from `Form`, and then `Form1` would inherit from `Class1`:

```
class Class1 : Form
{
    //...
}

public partial class Form1 : Class1
{
    //...
}
```

Make sure that all `partial` declarations inherit from `Class1` and not from `Form`.  (This would likely add an extra step for any auto-generated code, which is the classic reason for `partial` classes.  You might need to write your own automation for that.)

What's not clear to me is what you're trying to achieve by having an intermediate type between `Form` and `Form1`.  Is `Class1` supposed to be a generic "base form" that multiple forms will inherit?  Or are you trying to do something else?  But if you want `Form1` to be able to access members of `Class1` without exposing them as `public` members, you can make them `protected` instead.

Comment: I think it solves the immediate problem, but makes the long-term problem worse.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Very possibly, yes.  I think the OP needs to take a step back and more clearly define the need for inheritance in this situation.  Personally I find that inexperienced developers heavily over-use inheritance as a tool and end up with, paradoxically, very non-object-oriented designs.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance defines an 'is-a' relationship, so unless Form1 *is-a* Class1, then you're not approaching this in the right manner. You really have a few options depending on what you're trying to design:

1. Pass the form to the class instance through a public method, and let the class attach the event handler (this seems to make more sense in these cases, if there are multiple forms that share behaviour).
2. Store common behaviour in the form itself (as a special type of form, `PictureClickingForm`), and then let other forms inherit from that. Methods can now be protected.

This is a question of inheritance vs containment. Much more info about this when phrase the question in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can achieve the it by changing Class1.cs as below

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pb1 click");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the Picture Box itself public, but you will need to make the event handlers in Class1 public so they can be accessed elsewhere.

I don't really see a reason you should specifically require inheritance here. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to subscribe to `Form1` events from `Class1`? Try something like this:

```
//Form1.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 class1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        class1 = new Class1();
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new EventHandler(class1.pictureBox1_Click); 
    }
}

//Class1.cs 
class Class1
{

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pb1 click");
    }
}
```

It looks like what you are trying to do is not inheritance, but simply notifying an external object of GUI events. You should re-evaluate your code think about *exactly* what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form1 is a class, so just inherit Form2 from Form1.  (Instead of trying to copy parts back to some new Class1.cs file)  The Form1.designer.cs is still part of the Form1 definition, just moved aside for the purposes of the graphical form designer.  But notice that there are no other parts to the definition (not even for the designer!  Iy's all in there!).

Also, you don't have to make the classes public to make the pictureboxes accessible internally to the same assembly.

Options: You could create your own events in Form1, or you could create `abstract` or `virtual` methods for handling Form1's event occurrances with a subclass like Form2.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use always an interfaces. The point is you can inherit only from one class, but many interfaces... So i assume you would need such an interfaces - to pass the methods throught or whatever. Away from interface you can always put your class as a parameter to the constructor of second class Form (using 'this' keyword) so that you will be abble to pass values, methods from previous Forms let's say to another (e.g events also).